# Apollo GraphQl Query get data from two documents

Tags: graphql, apollo

i have a query and i want to go through two different documents, is it possible to do it ?

Document A { _id, senders_ID[sender_id]} 
Document B { sender_id, firstname} 
// i want to loop through document A and get each sender_id and go to document B to get the firstname.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it what you are looking for ?](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/react-apollo-migration.html#compose-to-render-composition)